# Continious CMS ERROR: 500 with Huawei E180 after some SMS sent

Tags: command, content-management-system, at-command, huawei-mobile-services

I am sending SMS using a Huawei GSM data card (modem). It is sending SMS properly, but after a while , e.g. sending 500 SMS, the sending stops and I get a

> CMS Error 500.

When I try to send other SMS, I always get the "CMS error 500". If I remove the modem from USB port, then connect it again, it sends the SMS properly for some SMS, but then the error appears again.

Some notes:

- If is use other 3rd party software for SMS sending, it gives the same error (which is also resolved by removing then reconnecting the modem again)
- This error only occurs when using the *Huawei E180* modem. When using the *Huwawei K3770*, it works properly without issues.

Who can tell me what the issue may be?